# No ipv4 connectivity over bond

Tags: linux, networking, systemd, bonding

I have the bonding driver loaded:

```
gentooserver / # lsmod | grep bonding
bonding               114688  0
```

I have a bond configured like so:

```
gentooserver / # cat /etc/systemd/network/bond0dhcp.network
[Match]
Name=bond0

[Network]
DHCP=yes

gentooserver / # cat /etc/systemd/network/bond0.netdev
[NetDev]
Name=bond0
Description=LAG/Bond to a switch
Kind=bond

[Bond]
Mode=802.3ad

gentooserver / # cat /etc/systemd/network/bond0.network
[Match]
Name=eno*

[Network]
Bond=bond0
```

ping4 doesn't work:

```
gentooserver / # ping4 google.com
PING google.com (172.217.2.238) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.38 (10.0.0.38) icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.38 (10.0.0.38) icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.38 (10.0.0.38) icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.38 (10.0.0.38) icmp_seq=4 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +4 errors, 100% packet loss, time 152ms
pipe 5
gentooserver / # ping4 8.8.8.8
PING 8.8.8.8 (8.8.8.8) 56(84) bytes of data.
From 10.0.0.38 icmp_seq=1 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.38 icmp_seq=2 Destination Host Unreachable
From 10.0.0.38 icmp_seq=3 Destination Host Unreachable
^C
--- 8.8.8.8 ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 0 received, +3 errors, 100% packet loss, time 137ms
pipe 4
```

ping6 works:

```
gentooserver / # ping6 google.com
PING google.com(dfw28s23-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4000:817::200e)) 56 data bytes
64 bytes from dfw28s23-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4000:817::200e): icmp_seq=1 ttl=54 time=30.8 ms
64 bytes from dfw28s23-in-x0e.1e100.net (2607:f8b0:4000:817::200e): icmp_seq=2 ttl=54 time=38.2 ms
^C
--- google.com ping statistics ---
2 packets transmitted, 2 received, 0% packet loss, time 82ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 30.797/34.479/38.162/3.687 ms
```

ifconfig:

```
gentooserver / # ifconfig
bond0: flags=5187<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MASTER,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.38  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 2605:6000:1020:395::1712  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:feac:3d91  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        inet6 2605:6000:1020:395:ec4:7aff:feac:3d91  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        inet6 2605:6000:1020:395:b72f:e4c:4281:3a7b  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x0<global>
        ether 0c:c4:7a:ac:3d:91  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 2798  bytes 384543 (375.5 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 2308  bytes 344136 (336.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 20 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

eno1: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.38  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        ether 0c:c4:7a:ac:3d:91  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1352  bytes 187718 (183.3 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1369  bytes 186668 (182.2 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfb200000-fb27ffff  

eno2: flags=6211<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,SLAVE,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.0.38  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.0.255
        inet6 fe80::a3b2:8bcf:adf8:8936  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0c:c4:7a:ac:3d:91  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 1446  bytes 196825 (192.2 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 939  bytes 157468 (153.7 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device memory 0xfb100000-fb17ffff  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 655  bytes 79944 (78.0 KiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 655  bytes 79944 (78.0 KiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

networkctl:

```
gentooserver / # networkctl -a status
● 1: lo
       Link File: /lib64/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: n/a
            Type: loopback
           State: carrier (unmanaged)
         Address: 127.0.0.1
                  ::1

● 2: eno1
       Link File: /lib64/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: /etc/systemd/network/bond0.network
            Type: ether
           State: routable (configuring)
            Path: pci-0000:06:00.0
          Driver: igb
          Vendor: Intel Corporation
           Model: I210 Gigabit Network Connection
      HW Address: 0c:c4:7a:ac:3d:91 (Super Micro Computer, Inc.)
         Address: 10.0.0.38
         Gateway: 10.0.0.1

● 3: eno2
       Link File: /lib64/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: /etc/systemd/network/bond0.network
            Type: ether
           State: routable (configuring)
            Path: pci-0000:07:00.0
          Driver: igb
          Vendor: Intel Corporation
           Model: I210 Gigabit Network Connection
      HW Address: 0c:c4:7a:ac:3d:91 (Super Micro Computer, Inc.)
         Address: 10.0.0.38
                  fe80::a3b2:8bcf:adf8:8936
         Gateway: 10.0.0.1

● 4: bond0
       Link File: /lib64/systemd/network/99-default.link
    Network File: /etc/systemd/network/bond0dhcp.network
            Type: bond
           State: routable (configured)
          Driver: bonding
      HW Address: 0c:c4:7a:ac:3d:91 (Super Micro Computer, Inc.)
         Address: 10.0.0.36
                  10.0.0.38
                  2605:6000:1020:395::1712
                  2605:6000:1020:395:ec4:7aff:feac:3d91
                  2605:6000:1020:395:b72f:e4c:4281:3a7b
                  fe80::ec4:7aff:feac:3d91
         Gateway: 10.0.0.1 (GIGA-BYTE TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD.)
                  10.0.0.1 (GIGA-BYTE TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD.)
                  fe80::1:1 (GIGA-BYTE TECHNOLOGY CO.,LTD.)
             DNS: 10.0.0.1
                  2605:6000:1020:395:96de:80ff:fea8:8096
```

/proc:

```
gentooserver / # cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0
Ethernet Channel Bonding Driver: v3.7.1 (April 27, 2011)

Bonding Mode: load balancing (round-robin)
MII Status: up
MII Polling Interval (ms): 0
Up Delay (ms): 0
Down Delay (ms): 0

Slave Interface: eno2
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 0c:c4:7a:ac:3d:91
Slave queue ID: 0

Slave Interface: eno1
MII Status: up
Speed: 1000 Mbps
Duplex: full
Link Failure Count: 0
Permanent HW addr: 0c:c4:7a:ac:3d:90
Slave queue ID: 0
```

ip addr:

```
gentooserver / # ip addr
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eno1: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:ac:3d:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.38/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eno1
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
3: eno2: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,SLAVE,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq master bond0 state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:ac:3d:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.38/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global noprefixroute eno2
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::a3b2:8bcf:adf8:8936/64 scope link tentative 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
4: bond0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,MASTER,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 0c:c4:7a:ac:3d:91 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.0.0.38/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global noprefixroute bond0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet 10.0.0.36/24 brd 10.0.0.255 scope global secondary dynamic bond0
       valid_lft 4074sec preferred_lft 4074sec
    inet6 2605:6000:1020:395::1712/128 scope global dynamic noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 4084sec preferred_lft 1384sec
    inet6 2605:6000:1020:395:ec4:7aff:feac:3d91/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86396sec preferred_lft 14396sec
    inet6 2605:6000:1020:395:b72f:e4c:4281:3a7b/64 scope global dynamic mngtmpaddr noprefixroute 
       valid_lft 86396sec preferred_lft 14396sec
    inet6 fe80::ec4:7aff:feac:3d91/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

ip -4 route:

```
gentooserver / # ip -4 route
default via 10.0.0.1 dev bond0 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.38 metric 204 
default via 10.0.0.1 dev bond0 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.36 metric 1024 
10.0.0.0/24 dev bond0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.38 metric 204 
10.0.0.1 dev bond0 proto dhcp scope link src 10.0.0.36 metric 1024
```

ip -6 route:

```
gentooserver / # ip -6 route
::1 dev lo proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
2605:6000:1020:395::/64 dev bond0 proto ra metric 204 mtu 1500 pref medium
2605:6000:1020:395::/64 dev bond0 proto ra metric 1024 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev bond0 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
fe80::/64 dev eno2 proto kernel metric 256 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev bond0 metric 256 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev eno1 metric 256 pref medium
ff00::/8 dev eno2 metric 256 pref medium
default via fe80::1:1 dev bond0 proto ra metric 204 mtu 1500 pref medium
default proto ra metric 1024 mtu 1500 
        nexthop via fe80::1:1 dev bond0 weight 1 
        nexthop via fe80::a263:91ff:fe7c:32a2 dev bond0 weight 1 pref medium
```

ip route get 8.8.8.8:

```
gentooserver / # ip route get 8.8.8.8
8.8.8.8 via 10.0.0.1 dev bond0 src 10.0.0.38 uid 0 
    cache
```

Comment: Can you show `cat /proc/net/bonding/bond0`, `ip addr`, `ip -4 route`, `ip -6 route` and `ip route get 8.8.8.8`? It looks like you have two DHCP clients and two IPv4 configurations (which ifconfig is incapable of showing).

Comment: Alright, I edited it.